# Problem on Hql query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have the following hql query:

```
from Admin a where a.genericTable is null or (a.genericTable.allowInsertion = true or a.genericTable.allowInsertion is null)
```

The problem is that the result set is excluding all entries that are comprised on filter: `a.genericTable is null`

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some example rows which you think should be returned?

Answer (score 1):

Try a left join:

```
from Admin as a left join a.genericTable as g
where (g is null or (g.allowInsertion = true or g.allowInsertion is null))
```